# C# Obscure error: file '' could not be refactored

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

Sometimes, I come across a property that, when I try to rename it using the built-in Visual Studio refactoring option, I get a dialog that says:

> The file '' could not be refactored.
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> Do you wish to continue with the
>   refactoring?
>
> [ ] Ignore further refactoring errors
>                                [   Yes   ] [   No   ]

The dialog actually shows empty apostrophes when referring to the file. Google doesn't provide any help. I'm beginning to think this is an obscure Visual Studio bug and that I should report it to Microsoft Connect. Thought I'd see if any of you have come across it before first.

FYI, my solution/projects build fine. The property is not referenced in any XAML. I tried deleting my ".suo" file, my "bin" directory, and my "obj" folder, then rebuilding, but still no dice. I have the latest Microsoft updates. The problem occurs with both Visual C# 2008 Express and Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Though it should not matter, the property looks like this:

```
private MigrationRequestViewModel Request
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

I have no problem renaming other properties in the same class in the same file, such as this one:

```
private MigrationRequestViewModel RequestSnapshot
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Any ideas? Note that I realize I could just find all reference to the property and manually rename it, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this error dialog.

Comment: Is this C++? Looks more like you're asking about C#.

Comment: "The problem occurs with both Visual C# 2008 Express and Visual Studio 2008 Professional" <-- so yes C# then.

Comment: sorry my bad, too many things at the same time in my head

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just googled the error message you would have found a word-by-word identical copy of your question on CodeProject which was posted already more than half a year ago:

> **[Obscure Error: The File '' Could Not Be Refactored](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/70701/Obscure-Error-The-File-Could-Not-Be-Refactored.aspx)**

The author of that question filed it on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550058/the-file-could-not-be-refactored) and Microsoft promised to fix it in a future release:

> Thanks for your feedback. We're aware
>   of this issue. This issue will not be
>   fixed in any VS2008 patches. Also,
>   this issue also exists in Visual
>   Studio 2010. However, we will strongly
>   consider addressing this issue in a
>   future release.
>
> As a workaround, you may be able to
>   get the refactor to work by first
>   loading any XAML file that exists in
>   your project.
>
> If you have any other questions or
>   issues, feel free to contact me
>   directly. My email is ramatthi (at)
>   microsoft (dot) com.

Comment: +1 This bug is still active in Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.  The solution is to make sure and have any XAML files open during the refactoring.

Comment: Bug still in there in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Comment: Bug still present in VS 2017.

Comment: Still present in VS2019 Preview 1.1.

Comment: It looks like he was copying questions from other sites.  He posted another question the next day that was also posted elsewhere, word-for-word, many months prior.  Is this something that should be brought to a moderator?  I can't imagine what the motive might have been, though there must have been some form of gain for someone or it would not have happened.

Comment: Still present in VS2019 Version 16.3.10

Comment: Still present in VS2019 Version 16.5.2... @Daniel it's possible they're just trying to consolidate questions onto SO to expand the platform's dataset, or they might be doing it for points.